# How to inquire StarTeam login credentials

Tags: wix, windows-installer, starteam

As custom action of a WiX-based installer (MS Windows 7), I need to check out some files from a StarTeam server. `stcmd` seems to provide all functionality and I am able to perform the checkout with UID and password provided via parameter `-p`.

Since the installer is run by different users, I obviously need a mechanism to **inquire the StarTeam login credentials at run-time** instead of hard-coding UID/pw.

I was browsing the StarTeam [manual](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.stcmdtools.doc%2FSTARTEAM-57C20EC2-CLIENTCOMMANDLINEOPERATIONSJUMPOFF.html) but was not able to figure out if the StarTeam programs provide a solution to that problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would an installer need to interact with a source control repos? Is this something your application could do instead after being installed?

Comment: My installed application is a plugin which consists of a set of script files (for the IBM Rational DOORS application) and a few more files. These files are stored in StarTeam and should be retrieved directly at installation time. This way, access control to those files is delegated to StarTeam.The installer will only install a mechanism which calls those scripts, some documentation and manipulate the environment so that everything may run. Perhaps I will forget about using WiX and use a simple install.bat file which should do as well, but the StarTeam credentials problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh, the solution is trivial. When using an *empty* password, `stcmd` automatically asks for the password. Example:

```
stcmd connect username:@hostname:portnumber
```

Using the stateful commands is recommended since the credentials are stored internally for all subsequent commands.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this just doesn't make sense to me.  Typically you include files from source control in the MSI at build time not install time.  What does install time buy you other then complexity?   Now application runtime would make sense to me.  You could create and install an application that prompts the user for creds and then periodically polls star team for updated files.  (Windows service, scheduled task, logon autorun...)

Comment: _What does install time buy you other then complexity?_ -> No need to rebuild and deploy the installer if only script files are updated. If the installer checks the files out, the users do not have to manually locate and check out (and forget some) required files -- they just re-apply the installer. Agreed, a batch file could do the job.
_Now application runtime would make sense to me._ -> The installed files are an application plugin. In the context the plugin is executed, it is not feasible to check out files.
_Windows service, scheduled task_ -> That would be rather bothersome, wouldn't it?

Comment: The scheduled task makes more sense to me.  That is the application and the installer merely installs it.   Setup a CI build on those scripts to publish them to a fixed network location and then code the application to merely pull down files from that location.  ("ever green")   Those scripts are considered user data to the installer and it doesn't need to worry about them unless you want them removed on uninstall.  In that case use RemoveFile tables to clean them up during the uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you could prompt your users for the login information during the install and then pass them to the stcmd.exe?

Comment: Absolutely! But I wonder if there is not a technique provided by StarTeam which deals with that. I mean, I am certainly not the only one who does something like that. =)

Comment: There might be a way using the SDK to have StarTeam prompt for username and password but I'm not sure. I don't work with StarTeam anymore. You might try asking in the StarTeam SDK forums: http://community.microfocus.com/borland/managetrack/starteam/f/